# Electromagnet with a hollow core

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, experimental-physics

For a project, i want an electromagnet with a hollow cylindrical space of 60mm(something Iike as shown in attached image) which can produce a force of 1000N inside this hollow space on a ferromagnetic object? Is this possible and how should i design or get such a type of electromagnet?[image: something like as shown in the attached image]

Comment: Iron tubes are for magnetic shielding, the field inside is small.

Answer (score 1):

The image shows a holding magnet ring. It works like a kind of circular horseshoe magnet. This kind of electromagnets holds iron plates that complete the "magnetic circuit" between the faces of the inner and the outer circumference.

At saturation, the holding power depends on the surface area of these faces. Just look in catalogs if you want to hold a weight of 100 kg.

There is almost no field in the hollow space.

Comment: Can you please provide or refer to any related catalogues? Because i am not able to find any catalogue for hollow core electromagnets.

Comment: @RajivKumar That is what I am trying to tell you: what you are looking for does not exist. There are *holding magnet rings*: for example here: https://www.hyab.se/en/products/el-magnets-electromagnets/el-holdmagnets?product_id=1981

Comment: I am looking to produce a force of 1000N on a ferromagnetic object with the help of any hollow object as i can't put anything above or below it, just like in solenoid valve system, where solenoid produces a force on plunger! Thank you!